# Replacing linoleum with vinyl

Tags: flooring, linoleum

I ripped up the linoleum in the kitchen to replace with water proof vinyl sheets.  Not all of the linoleum backing came up (see picture).  I doubt my ability to remove all of it without damaging the sub floor (I can get some more off easily, the rest may be a bear). Can I just put down leveling compound to even everything out or should I remove all of the linoleum backing?[image]

Comment: Any idea how old the linoleum is? I ask bc some linoleum may contain asbestos, which could affect your plans.

Comment: Well I already ripped it out.  Probably from 60's or 70's.

Comment: Don’t worry about the past (except to say that you should do a solid job cleaning up dust). Given the age, I’d either get it tested or just encapsulate it with 1/4” ply. (Add a bit of leveling compound to fill the dips under the ply.)

Comment: Sanding it without a mask is where the problem starts.  Vinyl sheets does not sound like it takes kindly to any height differences and go by @AloysiusDefenestrate comment.

Comment: @crip659 Ok, so I need to out 1/4" plywood on top and cannot set the vinyl directly on top without it?  That will offset the height with the flooring in the next rooms.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate  I have a related question here:  https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/275936/124084

Comment: Quite often people put down 1/4 wood before vinyl for a flat floor.  Possible with using a mask to pull up the old 1/4 inch, before putting down new 1/4.

Comment: @crip659. I see.  We don't have a 1/4" layer below our linoleum, the layer beneath is 5/8".  What I'm wondering is whether we need to put down the 1/4" plywood or whether we can flatten everything with leveling compound and install directly on top.

Comment: You need to flatten either way.