# Need to replace first layer of subfloor for vinyl install?

Tags: flooring, subfloor

We're replacing linoleum  in our kitchen with vinyl.  The rest of the house has hardwood floors so the kitchen has a second layer of subfloor to make it even with the wood in adjacent rooms.  Somebody mentioned the need to take off the top layer of subfloor and install a new layer.  The problem is the cabinets sit on that second layer as well.  Can't I just install on top of that second layer or do I really need to replace it?

For reference here are a couple photos of the 2 layer (linoleum sits on top of the particle board)[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what this "second layer" of subfloor is. There's the subfloor, then the floor, and then maybe other layers of floor on top.

You don't have to remove anything, and you can lay the vinyl on top. That is, assuming it's all perfectly straight and level. If it's not level, you have to fix that before.

And regarding the cabinets, you can lay the vinyl up to the toe kick boards. No need to fix what's under the cabinets.

Comment: Thanks.  There's a layer of plywood then a second layer of what looks like particle board.  I'll add some photos for reference.

Comment: That second layer is just something they put to help straighten out the bumps, then nail the linoleum to it

Comment: The second layer is probably helping you keep the floor flat, so I'd keep it

Comment: Flat, not necessarily level.